# how to send away ether in decimals?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, ico

say i have a function that give away dividend based on how many shares that customer owns:

```
// Give away dividend based on how many balances of each customer has
function giveAwayDividend(uint _value) onlyOwner {
for(uint i=0;i<size();i++){
    //balances[customerAddress[i]] = balances[customerAddress[i]].add(balances[customerAddress[i]]*_value/totalSupply);
    //Transfer(msg.sender, customerAddress[i], (balances[customerAddress[i]] * _value / totalSupply) );
    customerAddress[i].send((balances[customerAddress[i]] * _value) / totalSupply);
   }
}
```

the problem is, how should I be able to send ether in decimals? If customer A has 100coins, total supply is 50000 coins, dividend total amount is 10 ether, he should get 100/50000 * 10 = 0.02 ether, but here I think (balances[customerAddress[i]] * _value) / totalSupply will give me 0?

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where exactly is your problem in implementing 100/50000 * 10 = 0.02ETH ? Balances are handled in Wei bei default, 1 Wei * 10^18 = 1ETH, so 0.02ETH == 20000000000000000 Wei, use this [Unit Converter](https://etherunitconverter.com/).

I see a more fundamental problem in this: If `customerAddress[i]` gets long, calling `giveAwayDividend` will fail every time, running `out of gas`.

Comment: Oops, I just looked at Wei and you are right, there is no problem with my question. As for second question, how long exactly will that make my function fail? Because I only call it quarterly, it is fine to pay some money for that function call four times a year, if only each time it will successfully run

Comment: Glad I could help. Time is no issue here, it's the amount of payments. At a certain amount of addresses you pay out, the gas requirements will be too high.

Comment: Should this " 100/50000 * 10 " be "(10 * 100) / 50000" because of no floating point? I guess in this case, since the result of 100/50000 is an integer, it doesn't matter, but just curious.

Comment: Always avoid floting point situations, and write numbers as a multiplication with a factor which has an exponential, that way you avoid errors. e.g. if calculating ETH with wei, write 1 * 10^18 instead of 1000000000000000000.